# FireStore OnFailureListener is not called

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am searching some objects with their names in the FIRESTORE database and i have attached an Onsuccess and onfailure Listener to my get method but if some objects are not found it does not execute the body of  onfailure 
i have tried debuging it but failed to understand the issue.
i have also searched through many articles but it seems no one has encountered this type of error before.I have attached the screenshot from my logcat
below is my code

```
  @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<DeviceEntity>> call, final Response<List<DeviceEntity>> response) {

                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Log.i("Test", "onResponse: got the device name searching it in firestore");

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                        final int finalI = i;
                        Log.i("Test", "Devices that matched the saerch"+ response.body().get(finalI).getDeviceName());
                        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("Mobiles").document(response.body().get(finalI).getDeviceName())
                                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                MobileDataBaseObjectClass mb=documentSnapshot.toObject(MobileDataBaseObjectClass.class);
                                if (mb != null) {
                                    mb.setTimeStamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                                    Log.i(TAGo, "Success:getting the info from firestore");
                                    new insertAsyncTask(mdao,"firestore").execute(mb);
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
   Log.i(TAGo,"Onfailure listner"+e.toString());

                            }
                        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwzd2.png)

Comment: `onFailure` only executes when there was a problem reading the document (e.g. you don't have access to it). If the document doesn't exist, it should trigger `onSuccess`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank Van. i almost spent 4 hours searching for this Application is just working perfect now Thank you..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the comment by Frank van Puffelen is the right answer.

onFailure only executes when there was a problem reading the document (e.g. you don't have access to it). If the document doesn't exist, it should trigger onSuccess. – Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen